# Why I can't use scapy module in this simple application? An exception is raisd

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, scapy, python-module

I am pretty new in Python and I am finding some difficulties to use the **scapy** module into an application on which I am working on.
I am developing in Python 3 using PyCharm on a Kali Linux system.

I installed **scapy** performing this command:

```
pip install scapy-python3
Collecting scapy-python3
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4f/f3/e33d21e25b0dda2ffeebcc3ad06d26eff7f913c9b8b397c30f443b68b8e4/scapy-python3-0.26.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scapy-python3
  Running setup.py install for scapy-python3 ... done
Successfully installed scapy-python3-0.26
```

Ok then this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import scapy.all as scapy

def scan(ip):
    scapy.arping(ip)

scan("MY_IP_ADDRESS")
```

The problem is that running this script from PyCharm I obtain the following error message:

```
/root/Documents/PycharmWS/network_scanner/venv/bin/python /root/Documents/PycharmWS/network_scanner/network_scanner.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Documents/PycharmWS/network_scanner/network_scanner.py", line 3, in <module>
    import scapy.all as scapy
  File "/root/Documents/PycharmWS/network_scanner/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/all.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise Exception(msg)
Exception: 
        PIP package scapy-python3 used to provide scapy3k, which was a fork from scapy implementing python3 compatibility since 2016. This package was included in some of the Linux distros under name of python3-scapy. Starting from scapy version 2.4 (released in March, 2018) mainstream scapy supports python3. To reduce any confusion scapy3k was renamed to kamene. 
You should use either pip package kamene for scapy3k (see http://github.com/phaethon/kamene for differences in use) or mainstream scapy (pip package scapy, http://github.com/secdev/scapy).  


        PIP package scapy-python3 used to provide scapy3k, which was a fork from scapy implementing python3 compatibility since 2016. This package was included in some of the Linux distros under name of python3-scapy. Starting from scapy version 2.4 (released in March, 2018) mainstream scapy supports python3. To reduce any confusion scapy3k was renamed to kamene. 
You should use either pip package kamene for scapy3k (see http://github.com/phaethon/kamene for differences in use) or mainstream scapy (pip package scapy, http://github.com/secdev/scapy).  


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried either `pip install scapy` or  `pip install kamene` as the error message suggests?

Comment: @Axe319 yes both !!! The strange thing is that I discovered that from command line it is working but running it from the inside of PyCharm it go into error. Why?

Comment: The most likely cause is that PyCharm is using a different interpreter than the one you're using from command line and has different packages installed under it. Perhaps it's using a venv?